# I want make a OOP pagination for my articles

Tags: php, oop, pagination

I want make a pagination for my articles..

Here is class:

```
<?php

class Mynews {

    public $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mynews");
    }

    public function readAllarticles() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status='publish'";
        $query = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        return mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

}

$obj = new Mynews;
?>

display post: <?php
include('includes/crud.php');

foreach ($obj->readAllarticles() as $art) {
    extract($art);
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
    <p>
        <?php
        $post = explode(" ", $content);
        $slice = array_slice($post, 0, 10);
        echo implode(" ", $slice), '...';
        ?>
    </p>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Now i want a function my class to make a pagination... and sorry for my bad eng.. :(

Comment: Alright, please go ahead.

Comment: From the About page: `Don't ask about Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)` http://stackoverflow.com/about http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it:

```
<?php

class Pagination{
function Paginate($values,$per_page){
$total_values = count($values);

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$current_page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
$current_page = 1;
}
$counts = ceil($total_values / $per_page);
$param1 = ($current_page - 1) * $per_page;
$this->data = array_slice($values,$param1,$per_page);

for($x=1; $x<= $counts; $x++){
$numbers[] = $x;
}
return $numbers;
}
function fetchResult(){
$resultsValues = $this->data;
return $resultsValues;
}
}


// Sample Usage

$pag = new Pagination();
$data = array("Hello","Rex","Prosper","Adrivan","Hehe");
$numbers = $pag->Paginate($data,2);
$result = $pag->fetchResult();
foreach($result as $r){
echo '<div>'.$r.'</div>';

}

foreach($numbers as $num){
echo '<a href="classpagination.php?page='.$num.'">'.$num.'</a>';
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works for me

**PHP**

```
function pagination_one($webpage, $total_pages,$page){ 

    // Maximum number of links per page.  If exceeded, google style pagination is generated
    $max_links = 6; 
    $h=1; 
    if($page>$max_links){ 
        $h=(($h+$page)-$max_links); 
    } 
    if($page>=1){ 
        $max_links = $max_links+($page-1); 
    } 
    if($max_links>$total_pages){ 
        $max_links=$total_pages+1; 
    } 
    echo '<div class="page_numbers"> 
      <ul>'; 
    if($page>"1"){ 
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum=1">First</a></li> 
              <li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum='.($page-1).'">Prev</a></li> '; 
    } 

    if($total_pages!=1){ 
        for ($i=$h;$i<$max_links;$i++){ 
            if($i==$page){ 
                echo '<li><a class="current">'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
            } 
            else{ 
                echo '<li><a href="'.$webpage.?pagenum='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> </li>'; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    if(($page >="1")&&($page!=$total_pages)){ 
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum='.($page+1).'">Next</a></li> 
              <li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum='.$total_pages.'">Last</a></li>'; 
    } 

    echo '</ul> </div>'; 
}

function pagination_one($webpage, $total_pages,$page){ 

    // Maximum number of links per page.  If exceeded, google style pagination is generated
    $max_links = 6; 
    $h=1; 
    if($page>$max_links){ 
        $h=(($h+$page)-$max_links); 
    } 
    if($page>=1){ 
        $max_links = $max_links+($page-1); 
    } 
    if($max_links>$total_pages){ 
        $max_links=$total_pages+1; 
    } 
    echo '<div class="page_numbers"> 
      <ul>'; 
    if($page>"1"){ 
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum=1">First</a></li> 
              <li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum='.($page-1).'">Prev</a></li> '; 
    } 

    if($total_pages!=1){ 
        for ($i=$h;$i<$max_links;$i++){ 
            if($i==$page){ 
                echo '<li><a class="current">'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
            } 
            else{ 
                echo '<li><a href="'.$webpage.?pagenum='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> </li>'; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    if(($page >="1")&&($page!=$total_pages)){ 
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum='.($page+1).'">Next</a></li> 
              <li class="current"><a href="'.$webpage.'?pagenum='.$total_pages.'">Last</a></li>'; 
    } 

    echo '</ul> </div>'; 
}


// get the pagenum.  If it doesn't exist, set it to 1
if(isset($_GET['pagenum']) ? $page = $_GET['pagenum']:$page = 1);
// set the number of entries to appear on the page
$entries_per_page = 6;   
// total pages is rounded up to nearest integer
$total_pages = ceil($getresult/$entries_per_page); 
// offset is used by SQL query in the LIMIT
$offset = (($page * $entries_per_page) - $entries_per_page); 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status='publish' LIMIT $offset,$entries_per_page";

// do your query results

pagination_one('articles.php', $total_pages,$page);
```

and **CSS**

```
.page_numbers {
    width:100%;
    background:#fff9f0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    padding:50px 0;
}
.page_numbers ul, .pagenums ul {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
.page_numbers ul li,.pagenums ul li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:1px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
    background: #a8a189; 
    width:25px; 

}
.page_numbers ul li a, .pagenums ul li a {
    display:block;
    background: #fff; 
    border: 1px solid #a8a189; 
    padding:3px 6px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #7a7564; 
    font:bold 11px arial, verdana,sans-serif;
}

.page_numbers li.current,
.pagenums li.current{ 
  width:50px; 
} 

.page_numbers a.current, .page_numbers li a:hover,
.pagenums a.current, .pagenums li a:hover { 
    background: #a8a189; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```